# Why is Varnish not probing the backend server?

Tags: varnish, healthcheck

I have two backends for a Varnish configuration. The first backend works fine, the second backend seems to be completely ignored by Varnish. It seems that the `.probe` on the second backend is ignored in the sense that it never attempts to query the backend server. I say this because a `tcpdump` and logs on the backend server reveals no traffic at all.

A regular `curl` to the second backend server works well.

I've got the following configuration for a Varnish server.

```
vcl 4.0;

# import directors VMOD
import directors;

# define backend servers
backend apitomcat01 {
    .host = "apitomcat1";
    .port = "8080";
    .probe = {
        .timeout = 5s;
        .interval = 10s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 3;
        .request =
            "HEAD /api3/health HTTP/1.1"
            "User-Agent: varnish-health"
            "Host: apitomcat1:8080"
            "Connection: Close"
            "Accept: */*"
            "Authorization: Basic ABCDEFGH";
    }

}
backend apitomcat02 {
    .host = "apitomcat2";
    .port = "8081";
    .probe = {
        .timeout = 5s;
        .interval = 10s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 3;
        .request =
            "HEAD /api3/health HTTP/1.1"
            "User-Agent: varnish-health"
            "Host: apitomcat2:8081"
            "Connection: Close"
            "Accept: */*"
            "Authorization: ABCDEFGH";
    }

}

# create tomcat director
sub vcl_init {
    new tomcat = directors.round_robin();
    tomcat.add_backend(apitomcat01);
    tomcat.add_backend(apitomcat02);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # send all traffic to the tomcat director:
    set req.backend_hint = tomcat.backend();

    # pass all traffic - do not perform any caching for now
    return (pass);
}
```

*It is intentional that apitomcat01 and apitomcat02 use different ports.

Why is it that the apitomcat02 probe never seem to send any requests to apitomcat2? When i run `tcpdump -P inout | grep "apitomcat2"` nothing happens. I would expect at least to see the probe requests.

When i run `backend.list`, I get the following.

```
200
Backend name                   Refs   Admin      Probe
apitomcat01(192.168.41.51,,8080) 2      probe      Healthy 10/10
apitomcat02(192.168.41.52,,8081) 1      probe      Sick 0/10
```

When I run debug.health, I get the following.

```
200        
Backend apitomcat01 is Healthy
Current states  good: 10 threshold:  3 window: 10
Average responsetime of good probes: 0.068237
Oldest                                                    Newest
================================================================
4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444 Good IPv4
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Good Xmit
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR Good Recv
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH Happy
Backend apitomcat02 is Sick
Current states  good:  0 threshold:  3 window: 10
Average responsetime of good probes: 0.000000
Oldest                                                    Newest
================================================================
---------------------------------------------------------------- Happy
```

Comment: What is the output of ```varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health```? Run it for a minute and post the output here, please.

Comment: Turned out, after troubleshooting the issue for 3 hours, that SELinux was preventing varnish to contact the backends. SELinux had previously been disabled, but after restarting the server it went active again.